# Laravel 5.4 - Pagination method works wrong?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I've asked a question about the paginate method from laravel cause I couldn't make it to get the output I needed. I wanted to get all records where the name column contains a specific string.

Anyway, what happens is that I get the whole table content + the links are changing immediately:

The little code snippet ( I've tried many different thinks out )

```
$search = $request['search'];
$usergroups = Usergroups::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->paginate(3);
```

I'm not so sure but I think in my case there is an problem that doesn't come from my code. If I output $usergroups I get this:

```
current_page    1
data: 
   // my data 
from    1
last_page   2
next_page_url   "http://blabla.de/test?page=2"
path    "http://blabla.de/test"
per_page    3
prev_page_url   
to  3
total   5
```

You can clearly see that there is a total of 5 items ( and thats true, I've expected to get 5 items ), and there are 2 pages. Thats also true cause I've set the pagination to paginate(3).

If I output the links in my blade I get something like this:

[image]

But if I click on "2" - to get to the last page of that pagination, I don't know why but the links are changing immediately from 1-2 to 1-7.

[image]

Without reloading the page or anything.

So before I want to change the pagination link, I get the right amound of items, but if I change to ?page=2, I get all the items in my table. I don't know why but maybe thats a mistake by laravel. I've also tried it with laravel 5.3 ( currently 5.4 ) but got the same problem. If I look into the phpmyadmin query log and manually try the query out, I also get the perfect output. If I use ->get() instead of ->paginate(); I also get the output I want. I have no clue anymore. Maybe anyone knows an answer? Or something I can to? I don't want output my whole table if the user want to search for a specific item

Thanks for any advice and sorry because of my bad english!

---

search form:

```
<form id="search" action="{{ route("test") }}" method="get">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <p>
                    <small class="text-muted">Suche durch Stichwörter nach Gruppen!</small>
                </p>
                <input class="form-control searchbar" name="search" type="text"><br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Suchen</button>
            </form>
```

route :

```
Route::get('test', ['as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'Group\GroupController@test'] );
```

Controller:

```
$search = Input::get('search');
$usergroups = Usergroups::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        $usergroups = $usergroups->paginate(3);
        return view('test.test')->with('category_groups', $usergroups);
```

pagination snippet:

```
    {{ $usergroups->appends(['search' => request()->query('search')])->links() }}

        <div class="row">
            @foreach($usergroups as $group)
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="group-style">
                        <div class="list-group" style="border: none">
                            <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ $group['name'] }}</h4>
                                <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
                                    {{ $group['description'] }}
                                </p>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group">
                            <a target="_blank" href="{{ $group['link'] }}">
                                <div class="list-group-footer">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Beitreten!
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    {{ $usergroups->appends(['search' => request()->query('search')])->links() }}
```

The URL now looks like:

```
http://bla.bla.com/test?search=Test
```

Comment: just a hunch: what if you default the page value to 1 if not set? `page=1`

Comment: If I set the page value to ?page=1 before it was set ( so if I change /test to /test?page=1 the 1-2 pagination turns to 1-7. The output stays the same cause I allready are on ?page=1 ( even if it wasn't visible in the URL )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are appending the query strings to your pagination links

**Eg:**

```
$users->appends(['search' => $searchTerm])->links()
```

**Edit:**

Instead of :

```
 {{ $usergroups->links() }}
```

Append your query strings, like this :

```
 {{ $usergroups->appends(['search' => request()->query('search')])->links() }}
```

Comment: can you explain that again? Where do I need to place this code snippet?

Comment: Can you add your blade portion of pagination and the search form?

Comment: I've updated my answer, assuming your are using GET parameters. It should work

Comment: Here: `{{ $usergroups->appends(request()->input())->links() }}`. But yeah Ouail is right

Comment: My bad! I have two files that looks nearly the same. The orginal and the test blade. Sorry!!! Works PERFECT now !

Comment: Good to hear. Note : csrf token field is unnecessary for GET requests

Comment: yeah, I removed it and it worked. I've just haven't seen it where I was trying to fix the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `search` parameter is not added to the links of the paginator and because of that the number of pages increases.

By your code (`$search = $request['search']`) it's not clear if the parameter is sent by GET or POST, but my assumption is that you send it as POST and that's the reason it's not added to the links.

So, change it to GET and Laravel will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: I will try that and reply in a minute

Comment: I have a little problem with passing the input value to get. please have a look to the question, I will update it